# Nginx location /logs doesn't proxy pass correctly to Kibana leading to 404

Tags: docker, nginx, kibana, nginx-location

We have a dockerized architecture. The only and main entrypoint is our nginx. Which makes the link between all our services.

Reaching the domain name with location `/` works fine. Our Angular frontend app displays correctly.

The main problem is to access KIBANA (v5.5) on `/logs` location.

For example trying to reach `https://dev.example.com/logs/` the browser displays a 404 due to the fact it tries to reach https://dev.example.com/login?next=%2Flogs.

It seems Kibana, as proxied in our Location endpoint, tries to rewrite url with a base url of `/`. Instead of rewriting URI appended after /logs/ location.

How to improve our configuration to:
- Allow reaching of /logs/ which display our Kibana app correctly?

Here is our nginx configuration. Please note client, backend, kibana refers to docker hostnames.

```
server {
    listen  443;
    ssl     on;
    rdns    on;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/production/certs/example/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/production/certs/example/privkey.pem;

    server_name dev.example.com;

    # Angular APP
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Backend proxy
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend:9090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Logs on Kibana
    location /logs {
        proxy_pass http://kibana:5601;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Results of CURL request:

```
curl -v https://dev.example.com/logs/
* About to connect() to dev.example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* connected
* Connected to dev.example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=example.com
*        start date: 2017-08-23 17:26:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2017-11-21 17:26:00 GMT
*        subjectAltName: dev.example.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /logs HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.28.1
> Host: dev.example.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.13.1
< Date: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 15:39:43 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.1</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host dev.example.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: On which port your client application running on?

Comment: It runs on `80`

Comment: `/logs` should go to kibana, even if it errors out. Something is not right here. Can you add the results of `curl -v http://nginxip/logs` to your question, so one can see what is happening. Also nginx container logs to go with that would be best

Comment: In investigated the error and it seems that the problem is related with kibana itself. I have reworded my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `server.basePath` to `/logs` by passing the `SERVER_BASEPATH` environment variable to the kibana container.

Then, you need to strip the /logs prefix in nginx using a rewrite in the proxied location:

```
location /logs {
    rewrite ^/logs(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://kibana:5601;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Plus, there apparently is a bug in kibana, and the above configuration works only if we reach kibana with the following url:

```
http://nginxip/logs/
```

but not if we don't have an ending slash, such as:

```
http://nginxip/logs
```

To solve this, we need to add another rewrite in nginx to ensure there always is an ending slash. Add the following outside of the /logs location:

```
rewrite ^/logs$ /logs/;
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is where I ended: `location /logs/ {
  rewrite ^/logs(/.*)$ $1 last;
  proxy_pass http://kibana:5601;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }` but reaching /logs/ make me fall on the client (reached by /)

Comment: Ok I tried the whole setup on my machine and adjusted my answer. Hope it works for you, too

Comment: Thanks with break instead of final it works! Thanks for your help.